# How to train non-binary classification rpart with F1 as metric instead of accuracy?

Tags: r, machine-learning, settings, r-caret

I am using caret for my non-binary (three classes) decision tree classification. My dataset is skewed so I want to use F1 instead of accuracy for my training and testing. How do I set this?

For an MWE lets predict the cut in the diamonds dataset:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(caret)
inTrain <- createDataPartition(diamonds$cut, p=0.75, list=FALSE)
training <- diamonds[inTrain,]
testing <- diamonds[-inTrain,]
fitModel <- train(cut ~ ., training, method = "rpart")
```

How to use F1 here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The page at http://topepo.github.io/caret/training.html details how to create a new metric for the train function -

You need to create a new function with three parameters -

- data - "is a reference for a data frame or matrix with columns called obs and pred for the observed and predicted outcome values (either numeric data for regression or character values for classification)"
- lev - "is a character string that has the outcome factor levels taken from the training data. For regression, a value of NULL is passed into the function."
- name - "is a character string for the model being used"

The function should calculate the F-score for the observed labels and predicted labels in the data object, and name the result based on the metric -

for example a function calculating accuracy

```
summaryStats <- function (data, lev = NULL, model = NULL) {
  cor <- sum(data$pred==data$obs)
  incor  <- sum(data$pred!=data$obs)
  out <- cor/(cor + incor)
  names(out) <- c("acc")
  out
}
```

Then create a new trainControl object and train your model --

```
fitControl <- trainControl(summaryFunction = summaryStats)
fitModel <- train(cut ~ ., training, trControl = fitControl, metric = "acc", maximize=TRUE)
```

Comment: Sorry, that is not quite clear yet. What is this "new function" that you speak of? The `myNewFMeasureFuction`? How do I build the `data`-object? You say it would need and `obs`-column, but of course I have multiple predictor columns/variables. Where is the specification for `rpart`? The method would not be F1 - only the metric would be F1, so why does it say `method = "fmeasure"` in `train`?

Comment: Updated, added an example function as well - though since you are doing a multi-class problem be careful to make sure you are appropriately calculating micro or macro averaged F (whichever you want).